# Fabric.js: How to keep text from blurring as group grows larger

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

In fabricjs, version 1.7.20, I noticed that whenever a group grows beyond 1152 pixels (12in) then the text objects in the group begin to blur.  I'm programmatically setting the group size using the set() method when I need to grow the group.

Is there a way to keep them crisp/normal?  Should I be calling some other method on the text object or group so that the text remains readable?  I realize that the fonts are vectors but I'm not sure how to keep the font size constant regardless of the group size.

In this particular case I can't scale the group as I need the text object to stay the same size regardless of the group size.

Here is an example of the blurring effect:

https://jsfiddle.net/c7fn1e08/

Here is some example code as well:

```
var c = new fabric.Canvas('c');
var lbl = new fabric.Text('RESZING GROUP', { fontSize: 12 });
var g = new fabric.Group([lbl],{ top: 0, left: 0});
c.add(g);
c.renderAll();

var resizeGroup = function(g, sz) { 
  g.set({ height: fabric.util.parseUnit(sz), width: fabric.util.parseUnit(sz)});

  var l = g._objects[0];
  l.set({ top: -(g.height/2), left: -(g.width/2), text: 'GROUP SIZE '+sz}).setCoords();

  g.set({ dirty: true });

  g.canvas.renderAll();
}
//resizeGroup(g, '12in'); // looks good
//resizeGroup(g, '24in'); // looks bad
resizeGroup(g, '36in'); // looks really bad
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fabricjs, Lines in group become blurry](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47513180/fabricjs-lines-in-group-become-blurry)

Comment: Thanks for the link, that seemed to fix it - setting objectCaching to false:  

`var g = new fabric.Group([lbl],{ top: 0, left: 0, objectCaching: false });`